# Programmatically export to geotiff in different scales from ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, c#, export, geotiff-tiff

I would like to programatically export geotiff files in different scales (e.g. 1:25000, 1:50000 etc) using arcgis10.

As input I have some shape files and a DEM file as well as a corresponding style.

I tried to understand the different possibilities by reading the online-documentation but I am unsure what Api and Calls to use. 
C#, C++ and python are all ok but I would like to create a fully automated solution. I think a console application might be the best fit but executing a python script from within arcgis might also be ok.

I have the following questions:

1. Should I use the .Net API or is a python script sufficient in this scenario?
2. What are the commands / methods I have to call? A code example would be great but pointers to the right documentation is also nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a simple script using python.

1. Use the [dataframe scale property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000003000000) to define map scale within your defined map document
2. Use [Export to TIFF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000009000000) to generate new image file exported by dataframe extent

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). However I am currently struggling with a white boarder around the exportetd tif (even though I set the extent properly). Also the header of the tif is not complete. I think will add a new question and link it from here.